# PlayFramework2 required Jar files and recognising compiled sources 

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Finding hard to know why am I unable to get this thing :

[image: Image Shot]

... I can run my application from `command prompt`, But when I do `idea` and `Import` the existing project using `IntelliJ` unable to trace out what `Libraries` or `Jar` files I need to get going.

In one `Play1.2.3` I used to just Import `Play` and `Play1.2.3` `jar` files and everything works..

**Update**

Have tried Creating a new project and Open Project(Instead of Import) from **IntelliJ**,But no luck.It has attached all the Libraries but still the error doesnt go screenshot attached:

***IDE :IntelliJ 11.0.2 &
Play : 2.0.2***
[image]

Comment: Which version of Play 2 are you using exactly?

Comment: huh anonymous downvoting ? Downvoted for some reasons ? provide atleast info why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Play 2.0.2` you don't need to create Idea's project from the scratch and import modules into it.

Just choose `Open project` from the menu, and find the folder where you performed `play idea` action, whole project will be ready to use in the IDE without any additional steps.

**Edit:**

Most important: to reflect changes in managed sources your application need to compile it first, so it needs to work in the background while developing or you need to compile it manually if app is stopped. Otherwise Idea will not be able to compile (and find) managed sources. That's exactly job of the Play's `DEV` mode which differs from others Java frameworks, which requires to compile app manually and/or configuring your IDE to do that from time to time. Play's dev mode allows to do it in background.

Idea will start recognizing your managed sources after first run the app in the browser (as it will compile it, and idea will catch it just few seconds later). Of course the app must be running in dev mode, to compile views, assets etc.

```
play run
```

Of course if you're in production mode, you also need to restart the app.
alternatively after idealizing the project, or if your app is not working you can manually compile managed sources with:

```
play compile
```

Also if you'll start in tilde-dev mode, it will be compiling changed resources right after the changes' saving

```
play ~run
```

Comment: Have updated my Question, Thank you for looking into my issue

Comment: Well +1 for that .. `play run` has done the trick..the thing you mentioned were no where placed in the documents..couldnt understand what went through in the backend though..Finally? Cant I run app from `idea` the same way I used to do for 2.0.2..

Comment: What are you asking about in last comment exactly ? (after Finally)

Comment: sorry for not being clear I used to create run config in `idea` has `play.server.Server` has mainclass ..Is the same changed to `play.core.server.NettyServer` in version 2.0.2 ?Hope it is clear :)